# Nanomachines and deception are the essence of magic, how can I explain meteor showers and similar large-scale weather spells?

Tags: science-based, robots, weapon-mass-destruction, nanotechnology, illusion

So, dragons have access to this thing, called word magic. Word-magic spells are typically need way more energy and processing power than regular magic, they also have nasty cool-down times. A dragon has so-called spell slots, larger spells take up more slots and need more time to have prepared again, where as smaller ones take up less space and recharge faster.

Here are the most demanding spells, ones that you can use once a day and they take up all slots. (just a small sampling):

- **Planet Waves**: A frickin' meteor shower! Side note: they aren't actual meteors, they're bombs that explode upon impact. Ideal for setting smaller forts on fire.
- **Rain, rain go away, come again another day**: Make weather great again.
- **Weather Report**: Your turn to screw up the local weather, (figuratively) evaporate friend and foe alike with a lightning storm! Good for committing mass murder.

So, technology is the magic in this setting, its three key components are:

Robotics
Nanotechnology
Illusion (ya, know to make it look cooler)

Yet, I'm struggling to make sense of such large-scale spells, or at least their theoretical framework, I mean yeah, that shower is a bomb shower, but how can I even have them carried over the fort, then fly into the middle of the execution happening there and scream "Justice rains from above!" as Toto blesses hellfire down on the humans?

The same goes for the other two:

1. **Carry a bunch of shi- stuff high-up in the air.**
2. **Let it go.**

It's a simple formula, yet kinda hard to imagine, especially since the "magic" is keeping the thing aloft, I just signal when to start when screaming "Baby you're a Firework!" in draconic.

So, how could weather-manipulating spells like these work?

Comment: If you want to be technical about it... meteors can't make waves period.   Because they're meteorites upon impact (it's like saying that molten magma can never burn a house on a side of the volcano... because it's only magma inside of the volcano... on the outside it's lava.).

Comment: @hszmv Planet Waves is the name of the stand, not what it does.

Answer (score 3):

***Satellites.***

If you use magnetic field generators correctly and in enough quantity, you can alter the environment around you. If you were to equip a large satellite with a large EMF generator, you would hypothetically be able to alter the weather.

There are examples of this in real life...

[Weather Modification Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_modification)

[HAARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program)

And with the meteors, you mentioned Robotics and NanoTech...

You might redirect asteroids remotely with small nanobots, in which each has a small thruster that produces enough force to redirect the asteroid into the exact position that you targeted.

An alternate approach would be to disperse nanoparticles into the clouds, each NP equipped with an EMF generator and/or chemicals to alter/control the weather.

Comment: Is there any other way that doesn't require NASA?

Comment: EMF generator Nanobots...

Comment: for the meteor it remind me of gi joe project zeus by droping a big metalic rod